# May I post a series of questions to fact-check a book by a supposed quack?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

I am now holding the original, Polish edition of a book called "The Hidden Therapies - What your doctor won't tell you" authored by Jerzy Zięba, who is widely considered to be a quack by medical authorities in my country. Nevertheless, the sheer amount of facts (or "facts"?) and research papers cited by Mr. Zięba warrants some closer skeptical attention. He frequently cites books, articles, even research papers to back up his claims and sometimes accuses research that contradicts his claims of being falsified.

Among many other things Mr. Zięba claims that animal fat is not associated with an increased risk of cardiovascular diseases, is skeptical on vaccines and promotes curing thyroid diseases with large doses of iodine.

My last four questions:

- [Were the reference ranges of liver function tests set three times higher than their usual values during the research on the use of statins?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39749/were-the-reference-ranges-of-liver-function-tests-overrated-during-the-research)
- [Was there any scientic research backing up the setting of the reference range of cholesterol up to 200 mg/dl?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39748/was-there-any-scientic-research-backing-up-the-setting-of-the-norms-of-cholester)
- [Did Gary Taubes prove that cholesterol levels between 200 mg/dl and 240 mg/dl are normal and healthy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39746/did-gary-taubes-prove-that-cholesterol-levels-between-200-mg-dl-and-240-mg-dl-ar)
- [Was the cholesterol reference range set up to 200 mg/dl in order to to allow the research on statins on a wide range of population?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/was-the-cholesterol-norm-set-to-200-mg-dl-in-order-to-to-allow-pharmaceutic-corp)

are examples on how such a series of questions would look like. All those four questions attempt to fact-check only one little chapter of Mr Zięba's book that spans only 6 pages. (taking into account that both volumes are almost 800 pages long total, at a rate of 4 check-worthy claims every 6 pages… this would possibly mean a LOT of questions on this site)

I believe that the effort Mr. Zięba has put in making his claims at least apparently convincing warrants a similar effort to disprove them, so fewer people can be misled by him if they are indeed pieces of quackery (and in the case they were true... to promote new and revolutionary therapies and debunk conventional medical knowledge? Eh.)

I can see nothing wrong in posting such a series of questions, however, I think this would be unprecedented here, so I prefer to ask if it is OK.

May I continue in the future the series of questions checking claims from this book that I today started by these four questions?

EDIT: If someone was to raise notability issues, I believe this Wikipedia biogram will be enough: [https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerzy_Zięba](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerzy_Zi%C4%99ba) This biogram even provides further notability examples. His book is, apparently, a bestseller in my country.

Also: I am quoting vol. 2 of his book in the above questions. TO my best knowledge only vol. 1 was published in English.